# Parse JSON file android code already wrote

Tags: java, android, json

Hi im doing a request with this url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=26+rue+du+four+75006+paris&format=json&polygon_svg=1&addressdetails=1" (for example) and its return me a json file and i tried to parse it :

```
public class DepartureAddress  {

String adresseDepart = OsmRoadTaskActivity.Estartpoint.getText().toString();
static double lat;
static double lng;

public DepartureAddress() {

}

public static void getGPSCoordonates(String adresseDepart) {
    String adresseDepartFormate = adresseDepart.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    String url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+adresseDepartFormate+"&format=json&polygon_svg=1";
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String result = "";

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                stream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        stream.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            lat = jobject.getDouble("lat");
            lng = jobject.getDouble("lon");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

But the app puts a marker in the middle of the ocean... 
What am i missing ? 
Thanks

Comment: `sb.append((char)b);` is wrong. Your stream is in utf-8. You are reading each byte and considering it a complete character. It is not true in encodings such as utf-8

Comment: your url points to an empty jsonarray. your lat/lng ends up uninitialized (0, 0), hence in the middle of the ocean

Comment: (remove the zip code)

Comment: (or try with the correct one. (extra hint: 75006))

Comment: i corrected the url and im trying to improve my code..

Answer (score 0):

"http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=26+rue+du+four+75000+paris&format=json&polygon_svg=1&addressdetails=1"

is returning a JSON array and not an object. So you need to get the result in [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead of [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)